# How to create a single form field for two model fields in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have an older project which still uses Symfony 2. In it there is a form for editing a client profile. In the controller we have this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ClientProfile($remindTimes), $client);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

And in the `ClientProfile` class we have

```
class ClientProfile extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('client_name', 'text', array('label' => 'Full name'))
            ->add('client_address', 'text', array('label' => 'Address', 'required' => false))
            ->add('client_city', 'text', array('label' => 'City', 'required' => false))
            ->add('client_post_code', 'text', array('label' => 'Postal index', 'required' => false))
            ->add('client_email', 'email', array('label' => 'E-mail', 'required' => false));
    }
}
```

... and some other fields, but you get the gist. Then there's also a Twig view which renders the HTML. Standard stuff, as far as I can tell.

Now for my requirement. The client object has two special properties. Let's call them `FroobleEnabled` and `FroobleType`. If Frooble is disabled, then the type value has no meaning (can be set to 0). In the UI I want a dropdown with the values:

```
Disabled
Type 1
Type 2
Type 3
```

If the user selects `Disabled`, then `FroobleEnabled` gets set to `false` and `FroobleType` gets set to `0`. Otherwise `FroobleEnabled` gets set to `true` and `FroobleType` to `1`, `2` or `3` respectively.

How do I do this? The thing which makes this special is that it's not a 1:1 mapping anymore. There are two fields in the model object but just one UI control. I *think* I could achieve this with the a `DataMapper`, but I also don't want to manually map all the other fields (though I can, if there's no other option). I also cannot find any decent documentation about `DataMapper` or any other Symfony Forms features that could help me.

Comment: Could you use javascript to show or hide `FroobleType` based on the value of `FroobleEnabled`? The controller can change the value of `FroobleType` to 0 if the record 's `FroobleType` is changed to `Disabled`.

Comment: @geoB - I could, but I wanted to keep the ui simple.

Comment: An alternative is a single field with four possible choices. The controller can determine the proper values of the two properties. Doing this depends on the ability of users to make appropriate choices. Of course this is true for a two field solution as well.

Comment: @geoB - I'd quite much like to write some code that sets the two properties depending on the one input field. But _where_ do I put this code?

Comment: First choice would be the controller.

Comment: @geoB - Umm... I don't understand. See the code above. That's almost all that there is in the controller. The form fields aren't even defined there - they're in the `ClientProfile` class. The controller just creates the form object and passes it the field definition object (`ClientProfile`) and the actual entity. There's no place where I could intercept any mapping.

Comment: Controllers are also used to handle form submissions. Once the form is submitted and validated you can add logic to determine field values. See [this part of the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)..

Comment: So... I add an unmapped field to the form, and then handle the mapping manually in the controller?

Comment: That's right.  Controllers do most of the business logic.

Comment: OK, I'll try that.

Comment: @geoB - Alright, it worked!

Comment: Congratulations! Shall I summarize the above in an answer?

Comment: @geoB - That'd be great! I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to create a field, let's say, `frooble`.

- In the form class create a `frooble` Choice field with `mapped => false` and values 0, 1, 2, 3. Set its choices to strings appropriate to the application.
- In the controller, after form submission & validation, include code something like:

  ```
  ...
  $frooble = $form->get('frooble')->getData();
  if (0 === $frooble) {
      $client->setFroobleEnabled(false);
      $client->setFroobleType(0);
  } else {
      $client->setFroobleEnabled(true);
      $client->setFroobleType($frooble);
  }
  ```